# I225-IT driver for Ubuntu 20.04 on arm64 Architecture (AGX XAVIER)

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

I need the Linux driver(Ubuntu 20.04 & arm64 architecture-AGX XAVIER) of I225-IT which is said to be igc of INTEL.

Is there any user guide that instructs the steps of driver installation on LINUX?

Edit: I225-IT is an ethernet device.

`lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` command results as following:

```
 0001:01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0d9f] (rev 03)

      Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0000]

 0005:00:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1ad0] (rev a1)

      Kernel driver in use: pcieport

 0005:01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:154b] (rev 02)

      Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0000]
```

`uname -r` results as following:

```
 5.10.120-tegra
```

**aa@tegra-ubuntu:~$ modinfo igc | grep -i 0d9f**

**aa@tegra-ubuntu:~$ sudo modprobe igc**
[  126.576579] igc: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

**aa@tegra-ubuntu:~$ sudo dmesg | grep igc**

[  126.576579] igc: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel

Best Regards,

Comment: Is this an ethernet device? If so, please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` If it is not ethernet, please explain. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please see: "I asked the driver developers directly and it seems that there are no plans to support the IGC drivers for kernel versions < 5.*" from here: https://community.intel.com/t5/Embedded-Connectivity/No-I225-Linux-Driver-IGC-available/td-p/661813 I suggest you try a live session of Ubuntu 23.10. I am confident that your `igc` device will work there.

Comment: @chili555  Thank you very much for your support. I am not sure but kernel version should be 5.1 in the AGX XAVIER module.

Comment: Let's see: `uname -r`

Comment: I have edited the main message. uname-r results as  5.10.120-tegra

Comment: What does this tell us? `modinfo igc | grep -i 0d9f` Also: `sudo modprobe igc' and: `sudo dmesg | grep igc`

Comment: @chili555, I edited the main message according to your last question.

Answer (score 0):

I have two probable solutions. First, the driver `igc` is included by default in kernel versions 5.13 et seq: https://bugs.launchpad.net/intel/+bug/1945548

It is apparently supported in kernel versions 5.13 and newer; you are running 5.10-xx.

If possible, tether your phone and run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Since the current default kernel version for Ubuntu 20.04 is 5.15, I am quite confident that you will get a kernel update and, after the requested reboot, your ethernet will be working.

If tethering is not feasible, I suggest that you install a newer version such as 22.04 LTS.

I am unable to find any downloadable `igc` driver.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. I have tried the first solution but it concluded with some fix errors. On the other hand, the **sudo dmesg | grep igc** command was resulted with module verification failed message. In my older attempts I have tried to update default igc driver. I thought that igc module verifaction failed because of those updates. Hence I re-installed the same kernel and OS. Now, I225-IT is available as an ethernet port. Best Regards,